# timestamp null value from cassandra checking failed in java

Tags: java, cassandra, timestamp

In my form I'm not choosing the date, passing as empty for that field and in the db it is store as null. During edit i'm checking that timestamp value for null, while print the value is null. but while checking it with if condition it fails.

For this I compared the timestamp with null and length==0, if condition fails.

```
if(session.getAttribute("deliveryDate").toString()!=null){ 
   String delidate = session.getAttribute("deliveryDate").toString();

     ///////////////date convertion/////////////////
     long unixSecondsfrom = Long.parseLong(delidate); 
      // convert seconds to milliseconds
      Date datefrom = new java.util.Date(unixSecondsfrom); 
      // the format of your date
      SimpleDateFormat sdffrom = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
      String formattedFromDate = sdffrom.format(datefrom);
      ///////////////date convertion/////////////////
      page.set("deliveryDate", formattedFromDate);           

 }else{ page.set("deliveryDate", ""); }
```

when the timestamp is null I need the above condition to be false and it need to go else part.

Comment: `toString` must never return `null`.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *if condition fails*? Does it go into the `else` part, does it go into the wrong part, does it throw an exception, do you get a compile error, or what?

Comment: No it does not goes to else part. I tried without toString().

Answer (score 0):

The if statement has a casting to string that will be evaluated before the comparison to find out if it is a null value, as well as a double negative condition; you can solve it with:

```
if(session.getAttribute("deliveryDate")!=null) { 
    ...
```